# How can I speed up in for-loop? How can I improve the performance of code?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop

I want to improve the performance of my code. I tried few ways following advice before, but the speed of my code is still slow. What can I do instead of trying the way I tried?

My code is here:

```py
matched_word = []
for w in word_list:
    for str_ in dictionary:
        if str_ == w:
            matched_word.append(str_)
```

There are some points of reference here:

- First, the length of word_list is 160,000, and the length of dictionary is about 200,000.
- Second, I can not use a set of word_list because I want to make a list (`matched_word`) including duplicated words (the element of `word_list`).
- Third, the following code is still working slow.

```py
import collections
matched_word = collections.deque
for w in dictionary:
    if w in word_list:
        matched_word.append(w)
```

- Fourth, the following code is also still working slow.

```py
matched_word = [w for w in word_list if w in dictionary]
```

Thanks for your help.
(Thanks to all people who adviced before too.)

Comment: Please update your code with examples of `word_list` and `dictionary`.

Comment: Have you tried to use ``numpy`` arrays instead of lists? this could speed up the performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I can not use set of word_list because I want to make a list(= matched_word) including duplicated word(= the element of word_list).*

Due to how `list`s are implemented in `python` `.appending` might take relatively long time, `set` is not option due to above requirement, but there is structure in python standard library specially developed to allow rapid inserting at end, namely [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) from `collections` built-in module. Example usage

```
import collections
matched_word = collections.deque()
for w in ["A","B","C","A","B"]:
    matched_word.append(w)
matched_word_list = list(matched_word)
print(matched_word_list)
```

output

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B']
```

Comment: Appending to a list is already fast; what's slow is inserting at the *beginning* of the list. A `deque` is optimized to make insertions at *either* end fast (though inserting in the middle of either is still slower).

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to iterate over the dictionary; just check if `w` is a key. You are turning what should be an O(1) lookup into an O(n) scan.

```
matched_word = [w for w in word_list if w in dictionary]
```